# In Eclipse, how to find the control added to the toolbar by id?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have added a control to eclipse as below

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
<menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
 <toolbar id="my.toolbar">
   <control
        class="myplugin.debugger.toolbaritem.DebugDayMenu"
        id="my.yearmenu">
   </control>
```

I also created a class DebugDayMenu

```
public class DebugDayMenu extends WorkbenchWindowControlContribution{...
```

I now want to access this control in another place but when I try to do so using this code below, it results in a class cast exception

```
IContributionItem toolbar = coolBarManager.find("my.toolbar");
IToolBarManager toolbarManager=((ToolBarContributionItem2)toolbar).getToolBarManager();
WorkbenchWindowControlContribution dayMenu= (WorkbenchWindowControlContribution) toolbarManager.find("my.yearmenu");
```

dayMenu is instanceof DynamicToolBarContributionItem and NOT  WorkbenchWindowControlContribution ? Furthermore the control is embedded in a private field in DynamicToolBarContributionItem with no public accessor method

Is there a better way to do this or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would solve this in `createControl()` method of your contribution either by accessing necessary information or by adding itself as a listener of some sort.